# AWS Cloudformation nested stacks templates - how do handle local development and versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

Just started a simple AWS serverless project to test it out, so I'm developing locally and hosting the project on GitLab.

Wanna try [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html) just to split current template file into smaller pieces, but [`TemplateUrl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-stack.html#cfn-cloudformation-stack-templateurl) property value must be an url to a template file located in an S3 bucket, so I can't simply move my stack resources to another local yaml file and just include it in the parent one.

Manually upload nested stacks template files to an S3 bucket and than running `sam sync` from my console looks too intricate IMHO, and setting up a pipeline that take care of all the process too looks too much work for a simple personal learning project.
The fastest solution seems to be replace a deplyment pipeline with a script that can be run locally.

I know AWS cloud services are meant for enterpries-grade projects, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler and built-in/official way to handle all of this.